# why my answer was mark as down regarding a webform question?

Tags: discussion

I just answered a question this morning, and it was marked as down, but honestly, I don't know how to improve it? Ps: English is not my first language, but i still want to join this community. :)

Plz help me, thanks!
Question link:[Refreshing website design and architecture](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/230045/refreshing-website-design-and-architecture/230047#230047)

Answer (score 5):

The down-vote has been now been removed - presumably the voter saw the edit and realised that the answer was OK after all. No one is able to see who voted for what so this is only a guess on my part. If there is the kernel of a good answer then it will be edited into shape by other users. Most of us will offer constructive criticism where appropriate so read the comments and take on board what people are trying to tell you.

If English isn't your first language then it would be worth just reading the site for a while to get a feel for the sort of answers that are rewarded with votes. We like answers to be self contained and well reasoned.

I hesitate to suggest this, but something like Google Translate might be useful. Don't just post its output, but use that as the basis of your answer. Read it and understand what it produced so you can correct any mistakes it might have made.

Comment: thanks dude, I will do it using Google Translate if necessary!

Comment: @user3334708 You might want to look over the edits that gnat did in [revision 3](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/230047/revisions).  While the rules of punctuation, spacing and capitalization in English may take a bit of getting used to, being able to clearly present an idea can help avoid down votes.  You could also work on the answer in Google Docs and then use the tool 'translate this document' can help with larger blocks of translation.  It will also catch spelling errors (if you are writing in English).

Comment: @user3334708 another thing to check (just a quick search and yea, this one is ok) is online grammar checks - http://spellcheckplus.com was one that came at the top of the search.  Pasting your text into it and running a check on it does find a number of the issues that gnat corrected with an explanation of what the reason for the change is.  It won't catch the technical jargon (such as mvc and webforms), but it does do a good job with the basic English.

Comment: Thanks to MichaeIT, I saw the revision 3 and it helps me a lot, thanks again for you kind helps! I am going to try google translate !

Comment: Paragraph two is good advice for everybody, not just non-English speakers, and valid for every discussion site, not just Stack Exchange.